# Number of Integer sided triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Are there any formula or something finding no of integer sided triangle with sides from first "n" natural numbers?
I know that sum and difference of side of triangle rule.But how can we put that in action for this problem or are there any other way to solve.

Comment: Use recursion. Try to solve this problem using the number of incongruent triangles using sides {1,2,...,n-1}. Then, how many more do you need?

Comment: If you want to use a program to find them, then a quick to verify condition that sides $a,b,c$ must satisfy is that letting $p=(a+b+c)/2$ be the half perimeter, you have $p-a,p-b,p-c$ positive for the triangle to exist

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all $(a,b,c)$ with $n\ge a\ge b\ge c\ge 1$. First, do a bit of stupid brute-force programming to get an idea:

```
for n in range(1, 100):
  cnt = 0
  for a in range(1, n + 1):
    for b in range(1, a + 1):
      for c in range(1, b + 1):
        if b + c > a:
          cnt += 1
  print("n={} cnt={}".format(n, cnt))
```

Let this [run](https://ideone.com/2s62BD), feed the results into OEIS and you find http://oeis.org/A002623 which has a comment

> Also number of nondegenerate triangles that can be made from rods of length 1,2,3,4,...,n. - Alfred Bruckstein

and also some formulas, e.g. the one from Jerry Lewis:

$$a(n) = \frac{\frac{(2n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}6-\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}2\right\rfloor}4$$